# C++ Function to center text to a given size

Tags: c++, function, formatting

I'm in the 4th week of school and in my c++ class we are doing the truth table that I
already completed in both my PHP class and my JavaScript class.  So far we've only
learned cout for output (We're doing console applications).

We have learned about setw(), but I was hoping to center my text in a home-made table.
Can someone tell me how to write a function that inputs a string, and the total size of the field and returns the string centered in a filed of that size?

```
Example output I'm trying to generate:
+---+---+----+----+--------+--------+
| x | y | !x | !y | x && y | x || y |
+---+---+----+----+--------+--------+
| T | T | F  | F  |   T    |   T    |
+---+---+----+----+--------+--------+
| T | F | F  | T  |   F    |   T    |
+---+---+----+----+--------+--------+

Example code I want to use:

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

...

//Declare Constants and Variables
const char *COL1HDR = "x";
const int COL1SZ = strlen(COL1HDR) + 2; //  2 for padding L & R
const char *COL2HDR = "y";
const int COL2SZ = strlen(COL2HDR) + 2;
const char *COL3HDR = "!x";
const int COL3SZ = strlen(COL3HDR) + 2;
const char *COL4HDR = "!y";
const int COL4SZ = strlen(COL4HDR) + 2;
const char *COL5HDR = "x && y";
const int COL5SZ = strlen(COL5HDR) + 2;
const char *BOXPART = "+---+---+----+----+--------+--------+";
char c1a[COL1SZ+1], c2a[COL2SZ+1], c3a[COL3SZ+1],
     c4a[COL4SZ+1], c5a[COL5SZ+1];           // Will hold 'T', 'F' or Header
bool x, y; // two variables for the truth table
bool a // Boolean placeholder for the logic result

// Build Header Row
c1a = cntr(COL1HDR, COL1SZ);
c2a = cntr(COL2HDR, COL2SZ);
c3a = cntr(COL3HDR, COL3SZ);
c4a = cntr(COL4HDR, COL4SZ);
c5a = cntr(COL5HDR, COL5SZ);


//Display header of table
cout << BOXPART << endl;
cout << "|" << c1a << "|" << c2a << "|" << c3a  << "|" << c4a << "|" << c5a << "|\n";
cout << BOXPART << endl;

// Calculate first row of table
x = 1; // 0 = False,  1= True
y = 1;
a =  x     ; c1a = (a) ? 'T' : 'F'; c1a = cntr(c1a, COL1SZ);
a =       y; c2a = (a) ? 'T' : 'F'; c2a = cntr(c2a, COL2SZ);
a = !x     ; c3a = (a) ? 'T' : 'F'; c3a = cntr(c3a, COL3SZ);
a =      !y; c4a = (a) ? 'T' : 'F'; c4a = cntr(c4a, COL4SZ);
a =  x && y; c5a = (a) ? 'T' : 'F'; c5a = cntr(c5a, COL5SZ);

// Display first row of table
cout << "|" << c1a << "|" << c2a << "|" << c3a  << "|" << c4a << "|" << c5a << "|\n";
cout << BOXPART << endl;
```

So you know, the final truth table has many more columns than I've displayed here, but you get the idea.

If someone could tell me how to crete the cntr function, I would greatly appreciate it.  It would be helping me complete my homework, but in no way is it doing my homework for me.
(The formatting is my idea, and not part of the assignment.)

You can see the final table I'm trying to do at: http://skewl.us/truth.php
(I'm not nearly savy enough to add color.)

One final note:  I will reference this question/answers in my homework.  Which is to say I won't pass it off as my original work if someone helps me.

Thanks,
~d

Answer (score 0):

You could always "pad" the string until it reaches the center:

```
string Pad(string StringToPad, int Amount, string PadChars, bool Left)
{
    string Temp;
    for (std::size_t I = Amount; I > StringToPad.size(); --I)
        Temp += PadChars;

    return (Left ? (Temp + StringToPad) : (StringToPad + Temp));
}
```

Of course, if speed is a factor then you can swap that temp string for an `std::stringstream`.